# How do I utilize this tracking code with a button rather than a 'Thank You' page?

Tags: javascript, html

They've given me the following code to add to a 'Thank you' page; we don't have one so I'm looking to add it to the form submit button. Anyway here it is, more or less:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Unique IDs here

  (function() {
    var ct = document.createElement('script'); ct.type = 'text/javascript'; ct.async = true;
    ct.src = capterra_prefix + '/capterra_tracker.js?vid=' + capterra_vid + '&vkey=' + capterra_vkey;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ct, s);
  })();
</script>
```

I haven't really done any JS, so I'm not sure what's going on with their snippet, but i was hoping to just do something like..

```
  (function GIVEITANAME() {
    var ct = document.createElement('script'); ct.type = 'text/javascript'; ct.async = true;
    ct.src = capterra_prefix + '/capterra_tracker.js?vid=' + capterra_vid + '&vkey=' + capterra_vkey;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ct, s);
  })();
</script>

<input alt="button" name="submit" type="submit" id="test" value="click me"/ onclick="GIVEITANAME();>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Kill the parens around `GIVITANAME` and you're solid!

Comment: `"/ onclick="GIVEITANAME();>` to `" onclick="GIVEITANAME()">` perhaps? not sure why that slash and no quote there. And follow others to NOT use a self invoking function

Comment: Thanks guys, this is enough to go on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this. having `()` at the end of the function declaration will invoked it meaning it will fire when loaded.

`capterra_prefix,capterra_prefix,capterra_vid,capterra_vkey` - you need to pass them to your function to prevent the reference error or define them inside the function via `var` or `let`.

```js
 
function GIVEITANAME(capterra_prefix,capterra_vid,capterra_vkey) {
    var ct = document.createElement('script'); ct.type = 'text/javascript'; ct.async = true;
    ct.src = capterra_prefix + '/capterra_tracker.js?vid=' + capterra_vid + '&vkey=' + capterra_vkey;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ct, s);
};
```

```html
<input alt="button" name="submit" type="submit" id="test" value="click me" onclick="GIVEITANAME('test','test','test')">
```

Comment: @user1064397 well if that helps you, you can mark it correct :) anyway, you're welcome!